# Define a matrix depending on variable in Mathematica

Tags: python, matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I am translating my code from Python to Mathematica. I am trying to define a matrix, whose values depend on a variable chosen by the user, called `kappa`.
In Python the code looked like that:

```
    def getA(kappa):

        matrix = zeros((n, n), float)
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                matrix[i][j] = 2*math.cos((2*math.pi/n)*(abs(j-i))*kappa)
        n = 5
        return matrix
```

What I have done so far in Mathematica is the following piece of code:

```
n = 5

getA[kappa_] :=
A = Table[0.0, {n}, {n}];
For[i = 0, i < n, i++, 
  For[ j = 0, j < n, j++, 
   A[[i, j]] = 2*Cos[(2*pi/n)*(abs (j - i))*kappa]]]; 

b = getA[3]
```

But when I try to evaluate this matrix for a value of `kappa` equal to 3, I get the following error:

```
Set::partd: "Part specification A[[i,j]] is longer than depth of object.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
n = 5;
A = Table[2*Cos[(2 \[Pi]/n) (Abs[ j - i]) \[Kappa]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
b = A /. \[Kappa]->3
```

I'll leave you to package this into a function if you want to.

You write that you are trying to translate Python into Mathematica; your use of `For` loops suggests that you are trying to translate to *C-in-Mathematica*.  The first rule of Mathematica club is *don't use loops*.

Besides that you've made a number of small syntactical errors, such as using `abs()` where you should have had `Abs[]` (Mathematica's built-in functions all have names beginning with a capital letter, they wrap their arguments in `[` and `]`, not `(` and `)`), `pi` is not the name of the value of the ratio of a circle's diameter to its radius (it's called `\[Pi]`).  Note too that I've omitted the multiplication operator which is often not required.

Comment: how can I package all of this into a function? Maybe 'Module' is the way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, this would be the fastest and the most straightforward solution:

```
getA[κ_, n_] := ToeplitzMatrix[2 Cos[2 π κ Range[0, n - 1] / n]]
```